# R group bar chart for my senerio

Tags: r, bar-chart, frequency

I have 1000 categorical data sampled over 5 years which I collected which I may demonstrate as

```
senerio <- as.integer(runif(1000, min = 1, max = (4+1)))
```

the cases are numbers (1,2,3,4) with the first 181 integers for year1, the next 211 integer for  year2, the next 205 integers for year3, the next 185 integers for year4, and the last 218 integers for year5. all within a column. I want to draw a group bar chart with year as x-axis (with the case 1,2,3,4 being a sub-bars in the same x_axis) while the y-axis as the frequency of occurrence.

I want to know how many 1's in year1, year2, year3, year4 and also know how many 2s,3s,4s in each year.
my MWE which do no produce[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49fX.png)

```
barplot(senerio, legend = c("1",2","3","4"),beside=TRUE)
```

this is how I want the group chart to look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49fX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot is the likely solution. First, though, you will need to declare the years in your data. Below is a verbose example to show manually creating a dataframe and creating a years column, as well as a quick ggplot example. I'm not 100% sure I nailed you expected output. However,this is common question so this should provides you a start for exploring similar questions.

```
library(tidyverse)

senerio <- as.integer(runif(1000, min = 1, max = (4+1)))
senerio <- data.frame(senerio)
colnames(senerio) <- "value"
senerio$value <- as.factor(senerio$value)

senerio$years <- 0
senerio$years[1:181] <- 1 
senerio$years[182:392] <- 2
senerio$years[393:597] <- 3
senerio$years[598:782] <- 4
senerio$years[783:1000] <- 5


ggplot(senerio,aes(years,fill=value)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

Answer (score 0):

use ggplot2 :
`

```
library(ggplot2)
dat1 <- data.frame(
  gender = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

`
position is the important property for visual which you need.